# How to add shader to THREE.Object3D loaded from OBJMTLLoader

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, shader

I have a model loaded using [`THREE.OBJMTLLoader`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/OBJMTLLoader.js).

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
    var mesh = event.content;
    scene.add(mesh);
});
loader.load('model/machine.obj', 'model/machine.mtl');
```

I need to apply a vertex and fragment shader to this model. How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to Gero3's answer, this would ensure that all the meshes in the content will get the right material:

```
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

    uniforms: shader.uniforms,
    fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader,
    vertexShader: shader.vertexShader

} );

var object = event.content;
object.traverse( function ( child ) {

    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

        child.material = material;

    }

} );
scene.add( object );
```

Comment: It works! Glad to have this question answered by THREE.js's author! =D

Comment: Hi @mrdoob it says `shader is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

You need a shadermaterial for adding a vertex and fragment shader.

```
            var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

                fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader,
                vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
                uniforms: shader.uniforms

            } ),
```

Comment: I know this. It works for a box or sphere but for model, `event.content` don't have a material and if set the shader material to it, there's still nothing changed.